# How to show all customers who bought a specific product (with ID) in Magento 2.1.5?

Tags: magento2, orders, products, upselling

Is there any idea (SQL-statement) or extension on **how to show all customers that bought a specific product (id)** in Magento 2.1.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below SQL query to get `order_id`and `customer_email` of customers who bought a specific product with `product_id` 100.

```
select order_id, customer_email from sales_order_item JOIN sales_order on sales_order_item.order_id = sales_order.entity_id where sales_order_item.product_id = 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class .................
{

    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productFactory

    ) {

        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_productRepository = $productFactory;
    }


        function execute()
        {


                // Best Selling Products Overall

                $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

                 foreach($bestSellerProdcutCollection as $bestpdt)
                 {
                    $bestpdt->getId();
                 }



                // Get frequently boughted Products
                 $frequentlyBoughtedProducts = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
                  ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                  ->setPeriod('month'); //you can add period daily,yearly

                  foreach($frequentlyBoughtedProducts as $frqpdt)
                 {
                    $frqpdt->getId();
                 }

           }
    }
```

**Customize Based on your requirement** ,Hope this help you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Shafeel, maybe there is the possibility to get this via SQL – that would be easier for my purposes, but many thanks anyway!